# ASP.NET Button click event not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I have a code which i have put in and that does not seem to work in IE11. Can anyone please help me out ?

I am working in VS2005 and click event is not firing in localhost.I have tried the following fixes; hotfix from microsoft(microsoft update standalone package) and installed .Net framework 4.5 Even then button event is not firing.

Below is the code which I have put in - The aspx and the aspx.cs lines are mentioned below :

***aspx***

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExcelExport" runat="server" Text="Excel" OnClick="btnExcelExport_Click" />
```

***aspx.cs:***

```
  protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "You clicked a button.";
    }
```

Comment: does this work in Chrome/Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of your .NET framework, this is actually a bug. There's a patch available from Microsoft.

http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11

Answer (score 0):

Is your tag wrapped in a:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <!-- postbacks and other .NET client-based functionality require a 
         wrapping form tag -->
</form>
```